# Warning in .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#1043 Undefined array key 8

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin

After I added a new field to add picture in my users table in laravel, I am facing the below error in my phpmyadmin, only on the user table when I click on the Browse segment, I checked phpmyadmin version and it is 5.1.1 up to date, where my php is 8.0.12 version. I also added this line to config.ini $cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never'; after that the error disappeared, but I cannot see the data I entered to the table in the Browse segment which is annoying. Is there anyone to help me? I am new to laravel

> Warning in .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#1043  Undefined
> array key 8
>
> Backtrace
>
> Results.php#1174:
> PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTableHeadersForColumns( array, array,
> array, array, array, boolean false, string 'SELECT * FROM `users` ', )
> Results.php#4211: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTableHeaders( array,
> array, string 'SELECT * FROM `users` ', array, array, array, boolean
> false, ) Sql.php#1364: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTable( , array,
> array, boolean false, ) Sql.php#1620:
> PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable( , string
> './themes/pmahomme/img/', array, boolean true, integer 12, integer 12,
> NULL, , array, ) Sql.php#1856:
> PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getQueryResponseForResultsReturned( , array, string
> 'laravel', string

Comment: You said some changes caused the error, and that it was working before your changes. However, your question was "is there someone to help me"!? Answer: yes but we can't help without more details and clarity.

Comment: For example, post copy of each file's before and after (or at least parts changed).

Comment: thank you dear, I went over the same questions and answers. Majority of them say the problem is with phpMyAdmin version, but mine is up to date. However, I shut the server down on XAMPP and gave my computer an over night rest, now it is working. I am wondering what was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First take backup of your database, than create new database with different name and than import that backup file to new created database and than browse it your issue will be resolved.

Comment: I just exported the faulty table (mine was phpbb_users), then re-imported it, and everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open XAMPP Control panel and Stop Apache and Mysql services
2. Type phpmyadmin Download in browser and download the file
3. Go to downloaded file and extract
4. Go to C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
5. Copy config.inc.php file and paste to desktop
6. Select All files in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin and Delete
7. Copy All files in downloaded and Extracted phpmyadmin folder and paste in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
8. Copy config.inc.php from desktop to C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
9. Close C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin folder and Go to XAMPP Control panel and Start Apache and Mysql services
10. Browse http://localhost/phpmyadmin ==> Solved … Well Done!! Enjoy